# Assigning values to variable in an update statement which is in a trigger

Tags: mysql

I want to assign a value to my variable in my update statement which is in a trigger, but I get syntax errors when I try this code:

```
SET bc:= 0
UPDATE test.cashbook
Set balanceBroughtFoward = bc, balanceCarriedFoward = (bc:= totalCash - (Lodgement + Expenses) )
```

Comment: Can you please share the syntax error message

Comment: You have an error in your sql syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near ':= total Cash - (Lodgement - Expenses)) ' at line 24

Comment: @arulkumar do you know a solution to my problem? Please help